# Email templates using bamboo without phoenix

Tags: email, elixir, bamboo, plug

I am working on app in `elixir`. It sends email to clients. I am using `bamboo` library for sending emails.

So far, emails are working fine. But now, I am trying to send emails using templates. 
Everywhere i see in the bamboo documentation is using 
`bamboo.phoenix` .

I am not using `phoenix` for handling requests. I am using a library called `plug`. Is there a way to send templates in email without `phoenix` ??

Comment: As one way to go and I am not sure if it's a good one or not but you could use this -> https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html#function_from_file/5 to compile your own templates into functions and use them for rendering.

Comment: @JustMichael Interesting.  It also supports dynamic variables in templates. But have to check the performance.

Comment: I've done this before, but can't remember exactly how at the moment. Look at the phoenix source to see how they load templates. It should be a pretty easy copy pasta.

Comment: Phoenix is quite modular and built on plug, so you should be able to use Phoenix views just for the templating, but not phoenix Endpoint/Router/Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding answer to this post with the help @JustMichael comment.

**Directory structure** -

```
/priv
 /static
  /test.html.eex
```

**Function used** :

```
new_email
|> to("vivek29vivek@gmail.com")
|> from(@from_email)
|> subject("test")
|> html_body(EEx.eval_file("priv/static/mail_templates/#test.html.eex",[foo: "bar"]))  //this will render the template.Also can pass variables
```

**test.html.eex**

```
<h3>Foo: <%= foo %></h3>
```

But , we cannot add css just by adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` . I guess, There is a need for static server. 
Do comment if there is another way to add css apart from inline css.

Comment: I think the CSS can only be inlined (apart from using a static sefver) which is a good idea because it makes the email self-contained.